# Is there a way to check the schema of a table in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I know the UI has a schema browser that shows the columns and some info about caching, but I would like to be able to check this if I have the REST API disabled or do not have the port open to browse the web console of the server. How can I check this from SQL?

Answer (score 1):

These queries return table schema

```
tables

-- or 

select * from tables()

-- this to show columns by table name

show columns from <table>
```